# raspberry pi 4 cv2 and pandas importError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, opencv, raspberry-pi

If I import cv2 this happens:

```
pi4@pi:~ $ python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: libcblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>>
```

The module is installed and I tried everything, but nothing works.

I have a raspberry pi 4 model b with the standard raspberry pi os and python version 3.9.2.

Everything is up to date: the raspberry pi, pip and python.

I tried many different commands to install cv2 with: `sudo pip3 install opencv-python`, `sudo pip install opencv-python`, `pip install opencv-python` and I tried `apt` also.

The package is installed because i ran this command:

```
pi4@pi:~ $ pip install opencv-python
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (4.6.0.66)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from opencv-python) (1.19.5)
```

**Important !:**

I also can't import pandas:

```
pi4@pi:~ $ python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi4/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev
  File "/home/pi4/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "/home/pi4/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
  File "/home/pi4/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa:F401
  File "/home/pi4/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly  # noqa:F401
  File "/home/pi4/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 48 from C header, got 40 from PyObject
>>>
```

Is the problem that my raspberry pi is named pi4?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: wrong import. it is **not** `import opencv`. it is `import cv2 as cv` -- question is either unclear or due to a typo. please present a [mre] and review [ask] (question strikes me as lacking research). and your question lacks focus. you're asking about multiple problems. you might have thought they could be related or not... but they aren't.

Comment: Hi @Christoph Rackwitz, I know that you have to do import cv2, I just wanted to show you that the opencv-python module is installed, otherwise it would raise the error that you have when you import opencv (that doesn't excist).

Comment: I deleted the part with import opencv, sorry for the misunderstanding. But this still doens't solve my problem. I just want to work with cv2 on my raspberry pi, but everytime I import an installed pacage, it raises a long error (like the ones I get with cv2 and pandas)

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands:

```
pip install opencv-python
pip install -U numpy
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install -y libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libgtk-3-dev libavcodec-extra libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libjasper1 libjasper-dev libatlas-base-dev gfortran libeigen3-dev libtbb-dev
```

Comment: wow I didn't expect an answer anymore :) Thanks!! I will try it out as soon as i can